# PRAW: Get User's Flair

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to using PRAW to organize all comments by users active in /r/nba based on their flair. Is there a good way get a user's flair if I have the username?

My end goal is to perform some text analysis on user comments grouped by NBA fandom. thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Found it - for anyone who had trouble with this, just use author_flair_text